# using xpath to get `for $a in distinct-values` sub elements in xquery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Simple example:

sample.xml

```
<customers>
  <customer>
    <name>Tony</name>
    <order>Burger</order>
    <id>1234</id>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <name>Kate</name>
    <order>Soda</order>
    <id>5678</id>
  </customer>
</customers
```

with the XQuery

```
for $a in distinct-values(doc("sample.xml")/customers/customer)
return
$y
```

will return

```
Tony
Burger
1234

Kate
Soda
5678
```

However if I do:

```
for $a in distinct-values(doc("sample.xml")/customers/customer)
return
$y/name
```

To only return the names, it throws me an error. Can anyone explain why? I want to access certain values instead of the whole tree. Same thing if I try to do anything with $y/(something) like use it in a where expression.

Update: I figured out how to somewhat bypass my overall problem by using distinct-values() as a return expression however I'm still confused why I'm not allowed to access sub elements in distinct-values for loops

Comment: Do you really need the distinct-values? Do customers occur multiple times in your xml doc?

Answer (score 0):

distinct-values() will convert the input into atomic values. This means that only the content will be returned and thus the xml representation will be lost.

If you really want to do this you could maybe use something like the custom function: functx:distinct-deep: http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_distinct-deep.html

But keep in mind that you don't want to do this in most cases, it's also likely pretty bad for performance

Comment: Is there any way to manipulate the return content at all? Or can it only be displayed as is?

Comment: Is there absolutely no way to do it without the use of custom functions? If there isn't then I will use it however surely there is a way to do it without them.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to query. In the query you've shown I don't see a need for distinct values at all since customers should already be unique? For other cases you might want one specific value to be unique, maybe in that case you could use group by, etc. If you come up with some specific example then we can show you how to best query it.